# Showing this Null homotopic composite factors through a Null homotopic map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was having some trouble with this concept which makes sense to me intuitively but the understanding of which is not yet fully clear.

Suppose $CS^n$ is the unreduced cone on the n-sphere $S^n$. By unreduced, I mean $CS^n=S^n\times I/S^n\times \{1\}$. We have a map $g:S^n \rightarrow CS^n$ and a map $e: CS^n \rightarrow Z$ for a space $Z$ where $e \circ g$ is null homotopic.

I assumed all maps are based and that $e \circ g$ is homotopic to some constant map $ c:S^n \rightarrow Z$ at the point $e(g(1))$. This gives a triangular diagram (composed of e,g, and c) which commutes up to homotopy. It seems reasonable to conclude that $g$ is null homotopic. I am not fully confident in this.

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The cone is homeomorphic to the closed ball $D^n$. Do you know a topological property of the ball that might be relevant?

Comment: Contractible? I think that should do it.

Comment: Right. So every continuous map $S^n \to CS^n$ is nullhomotopic (with fixed base point, if desired), as is every continuous map $CS^n \to X$, whatever $X$ is.

Comment: Well, every cone is contractible...